# How do I count the amount of cells that contain a formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to count the amount of cells that contain a function in them without having `=ISFUNCTION(cell)` next to every single cell and counting the amount of cells that return TRUE.

I tried to use `=SUMPRODUCT(INT(ISFUNCTION(A3:A)))`, but this only returns 1 or 0. When testing this same method with `=SUMPRODUCT(INT(ISTEXT(A3:A)))`, it returns the number of cells that contain text, similar to what I'd want isFunction to do. I'm not sure why it works with isText but not with isFunction.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). There is no `isfunction()` spreadsheet function in Google Sheets — you are probably referring to `isformula()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `isformula()` spreadsheet function does not work in an array formula, so you will have to use a script, perhaps a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) like this:

```
/**
* Counts the number of spreadsheet formulas in a range.
*
* @param {"A2:A42"} rangeA1 A text string that specifies the cell range where to count formulas.
* @param {A2:A42} dynamic_reference Optional. The same range as a normal range reference, to ensure that the results update dynamically.
* @return {Number} The number of spreadsheet formulas in rangeA1.
* @customfunction
*/
function CountFormulas(rangeA1, dynamic_reference) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 28 October 2021
  if (typeof rangeA1 !== 'string') {
    throw new Error('CountFormulas expected rangeA1 to be a text string like "A2:A42" but got ' + Object.prototype.toString.call(rangeA1) + ' instead.');
  }
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rangeA1);
  const formulas = range.getFormulas().flat().filter(String);
  return formulas.length;
}
```

Use the custom function like this:

`=CountFormulas("A3:A", A3:A)`

Comment: Excellent adaptation.